# C# Selenium PhantomJS element(s) not found

Tags: c#, selenium, phantomjs

I'm trying to get the full page source from [this website](https://seller.shopee.co.id/account/signin?next=index.index&params=%5B%5D) using Selenium and PhantomJS, but it can't get the full page source, only this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html class="uiSecureRoutePopup uiProductShipOutIn uiLanguageChooser uiShippingAvgPrepTime uiProductPreorder uiProductPreorderCrossborderSupport uiOrderArrangePickupCanEdit orderAftership uiOrderMassShipOpenToAllUsers uiOrderMassShipAutoConsignment uiOrderFilterInToShip uiMassShipPoslajuIntegrated uiShopImportRuten uiIncomeExportAddVoucher massUploadShipDays uiMassUpdateOpenToAllUsers embeddedChat uiPaymentServices uiUnlinkPaymentService uiBankAccountAllowLastAccountDeletion uiLogisticsPoslajuPickupWhitelist uiMassUpdateDaysToShip uiOTPSecurity uiOTPSecurityChangePassword uiOTPSecurityChangeBank uiOTPSecurityChangePhone closeOfflinePayment allowTurnOffDefaultOnlyChannel uiWholesale productLevelLogistics productLevelLogisticsMassUpdate uiAdsPortal uiTHDisabledLogisticsHidePrice uiGoJekLogistics uiNumericalWalletLimit uiAdsUseTimestamps uiWalletPaymentTransactionFilter uiRatingReply uiPLSShopDefaultLogistics uiBeatAdBlock uiVoucher uiAdsReportingItemSoldGMV uiProductAttributeQualityControl uiGoJekErrorMessageImprovements touchevents no-flexbox"><head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title></title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1200">
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">

<meta name="ads-portal/config/environment" content="%7B%22modulePrefix%22%3A%22ads-portal%22%2C%22environment%22%3A%22production%22%2C%22dependencyImport%22%3A%7B%22helper%22%3A%5B%22inline-svg%22%2C%22cdn-file%22%2C%22validator%22%2C%22feature-flag%22%5D%2C%22component%22%3A%5B%22shopee-price%22%2C%22product/basic-item%22%2C%22shopee-dropdown-period-picker%22%2C%22no-result%22%5D%7D%2C%22shopeeEmberCommon%22%3A%7B%22country%22%3A%22sg%22%7D%7D">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.shopee.co.id/shopee/shopee-seller-static-live-id/assets/vendor-61977354650bc2f42cdf2a723a05b1bd.css" integrity="sha256-86Gd79yhCZrS0YoMKNMnRUgHp5qyLcaxP2iIUcCfBoE= sha512-CIA0hfIykimLMaTEekxDlvlg3NzcC+Vb7Lb0FNg/bwZssfxqQlgiNA9cACwOqhPwcNlCvvmcgeclvVYtsIUg1w==" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.shopee.co.id/shopee/shopee-seller-static-live-id/assets/seller-2cd97775ac239c622e92d6b785b6173d.css">
    <meta name="seller/config/asset-manifest" content="%7B%22bundles%22%3A%7B%22ads-portal%22%3A%7B%22assets%22%3A%5B%7B%22uri%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.shopee.co.id%2Fshopee%2Fshopee-seller-static-live-id%2Fengines-dist%2Fads-portal%2Fassets%2Fengine-vendor-f629d8e9a5b174e0b10379b61b1d6a89.css%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22css%22%7D%2C%7B%22uri%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.shopee.co.id%2Fshopee%2Fshopee-seller-static-live-id%2Fengines-dist%2Fads-portal%2Fassets%2Fengine-vendor-edf7ea3ec3561c7f06b64ecb02eaa792.js%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22js%22%7D%2C%7B%22uri%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.shopee.co.id%2Fshopee%2Fshopee-seller-static-live-id%2Fengines-dist%2Fads-portal%2Fassets%2Fengine-d3bc5a4128a2ad34710eb812a7d375b0.css%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22css%22%7D%2C%7B%22uri%22%3A%22https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.shopee.co.id%2Fshopee%2Fshopee-seller-static-live-id%2Fengines-dist%2Fads-portal%2Fassets%2Fengine-77fa2ffdad40c9e68fb501548252ec1c.js%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22js%22%7D%5D%7D%7D%7D">
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
  <script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js?_=1497786568487"></script></head>
  <body>

    <div id="shopee-powerseller-root" style="height:100%; min-height:100%;" class="ember-application"></div>
    <div id="shopee-chat-embedded" style="z-index: 99999; position: fixed; right: 70px; bottom: 0;"></div>

    <script src="https://cdn.shopee.co.id/shopee/shopee-seller-static-live-id/assets/vendor-b3476ceab28d140e360d81006f6350c4.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.ravenjs.com/3.12.1/raven.min.js" integrity="sha384-Xsu9Kcp/8TUx5byUpQAwCO2ByWnABezqEqRw4j5RwiAF9dzn3/9lazwDT1RDg5Pe" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.shopee.co.id/shopee/shopee-seller-static-live-id/assets/seller-0f71e00ef5525918738a48cf55273001.js"></script>

    <audio class="beep-sound" preload="none">
      <source src="https://cdn.shopee.co.id/shopee/shopee-seller-static-live-id/sound/notification.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
</body></html>
```

---

**My code:**

```
public static Func<IWebDriver, IWebElement> ElementToBeClickable(By locator)
    {
        return driver =>
        {
            var element = driver.FindElement(locator);
            return (element != null && element.Displayed && element.Enabled) ? element : null;
        };
    }

            PhantomJSDriverService service = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
             service.SslProtocol = "tlsv1";
             service.WebSecurity = false;
             service.IgnoreSslErrors = true;

             var driver = new PhantomJSDriver(service);
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://seller.shopee.co.id/account/signin?next=index.index&params=%5B%5D");

        //driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(40));

        var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//input[contains(@placeholder, 'Username')]")));
        Console.WriteLine(driver.PageSource);
```

**Output:**

> [ERROR - 2017-06-18T13:54:11.563Z] WebElementLocator - _handleLocateCommand - Element(s) NOT Found: GAVE UP. Search Stop Time: 1497794051508

How to fix this?

Comment: What line of the code is causing that output to occur?

Comment: wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//input[contains(@placeholder, 'Username')]")));
i think it can't find the input because phantomjs not fully loaded the page